# TSQL Summing to a value

Tags: t-sql

I am looking to take a table like the one below. Code is a part that exists on a job, and Value are the different cut lengths of that part needed. Ultimately, I want to sum as many of these cuts that I can get out of a full bar which would equal 1.

```
Code    Value
X   0.10000000
X   0.40000000
X   0.64000000
X   0.30000000
X   0.52000000
```

Expected End Results is

```
Code    Value
X       .8
X       .64
X       .52
```

I am not sure the best way of saying it but I want to sum all rows grouping by the Part Code and return as many results of the Sum that do not exceed my predetermined value of 1...

Comment: How many rows are you looking to do this with? This will get quickly out of hand as the number of potential combinations that could equal one (weighing each of them as a set to see which one is "best") is going to become a VERY large number VERY quickly.

Comment: There are other combination as well lower than 1 - `.5`, `.74`, `.94` to name a few. What's the logic to favor one over the other?

Comment: And speaking of the different sets of records that equal 1 when summed with one or more records... which one would you consider "Best" of those sets? The one with more results? one with less? one that averges closest to 1? Why choose this particular answer as your desired results over the 3 or 4 other sets that are available with this sample data?

Comment: There is no preference on the different sets that could be made here. There could be a ton of different cuts for each part the end game is to sum up as many as possible to find the least amount of bars needed, for the specified part.

Comment: "The least amount of bars needed for the specific part" is the preference then? I'm assuming when you say "Bars" you are meaning initial records?

Comment: This one of those things that you could *probably* do in SQL, but shouldn't.

Comment: Yes for example if my part was a 19 foot bar, and my job is calling for the .4 you don't need to do the math as far as feet an inches is concerned that is already done for you. The .4 is saying I need .4 of that 19 foot bar, which is why I am looking to Sum to the value of 1

Comment: I feel like I am going to need a CTE rucursive query but I know so little about that that I am not sure.

Comment: I think a Recursive CTE is going to be *part* of this solution. It will give you a set of possible sets. But again, back to my first question, how big will the initial record set be that feeds into this?If it's less than like 50 to 100ish maybe... this is doable. If it's more than that though I think you are going to end up with unfathomably huge number of potential sets of sets which will take forever to actually generate, then you have to apply some logic to pick the "best" (the one with the least number of elements).

Comment: JNevill thanks for the help. Yes there is going to be a large number of rows to apply this to. the "X" represents one part, there are multiple parts on each job, and multiple jobs.I am just trying to get the logic on a smaller scale, and from there the more I learn the more I will be able to apply ways to optimize the code.

Comment: This is not the type of task that SQL is "good" at.  You can do it with a stored procedure or recursive CTE.  It sounds like a bad design to me -- maybe you want to do this on the front end?

Comment: Could you guys supply the code. Not sure how I would do this in an SSRS report. Whatever examples you can provide me is what I am looking for. Please show me how you would go about achieving this if not in the SQL code.